# How can I enable 'Connect through cloud servers' in torrc?

Tags: bridge, tor-cloud

In Orbot there is an option for bridges like this:
[image]

How can I enable this feature in torrc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/bridges for information on adding bridges

I think that particular setting though is specific to the app and may not have a torrc equivalent